# IEnumerable<T>.Cast won't work even if an explicit cast operator is defined?

Tags: c#

I have an explicit conversion defined from type `Bar` to type `Foo`.

```
public class Bar
{
  public static explicit operator Foo(Bar bar)
  {
    return new Foo(bar.Gar);
  }
}

public class Foo
{
  public string Gar { get; set; }

  public Foo() { }

  public Foo(string gar) { Gar = gar; }
}
```

However, when I do:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var manyFoos = manyBars.Cast<Foo>();
```

It throws an exception saying it can't cast.

How do I tell `Cast` to use my cast operator to try the conversion?

Comment: You have `Bar`->`Foo` conversion defined, but trying to do the opposite.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I meant the opposite. I just typed that code directly into the website without thinking too much. I've made the correction.

Comment: Still not correct. `bar.Gar`? where does this come from? bar doesn't have property `Gar`

Comment: That's implicit. That's not an oversight. It was left intentionally. I am not a newbie. Please don't state the obvious.

Answer (score 12):

[Conversion operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) are static methods that the **compiler** calls when you use casts in code. They cannot be used dynamically. `Enumerable.Cast` does a runtime cast of two unconstrained generic types, so it cannot know during compile time which cast operators to use. To do what you want, you can use `Select`:

```
manyFoos.Select(foo => (Bar)foo);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of how to get around it using a projection. I was just thinking it would have been nice for `Cast` or `OfType`, though I am not filtering here and `OfType` would not be appropriate, should use our custom cast. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: This is wrong. There is no such thing as a _cast_ operator; it's a _conversion_ operator. Furthermore, `Enumerable.Cast` attempts a _compile time_  cast / conversion; the reason this fails is because `Enumerable.Cast` accepts a non-generic `IEnumerable`, and because custom conversion operators are evaluated at compile time, there is no conversion from `object` to `Bar`.

Answer (score 6):

The linq `Cast` method essentially does a box and unbox. It is not aware of either implicit or explicit cast operators defined in C#, which the compiler treats standard method calls.

You'd have to do something like this:

```
var manyFoos = manyBars.Select(bar => (Foo)bar);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just hoping to have some built-in method or extension such as `Cast` or `OfType` use my cast because many times I have bumped into this situation. I will use a transform for now anyway.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 You could probably write your own extension method, perhaps one that uses reflection. But that would be neither as elegant nor efficient as what you're probably looking for. I'd stick with this method unless you *really* to do dynamic casting.

Answer (score 5):

As all other answers pointed type is not known in compile time since `Cast` method is not `generic`. It holds type of `object` and makes a explicit cast to `T`. this fails because you don't have conversion operator from `object` to `Foo`. And that is not possible also.

Here is a work around using dynamics in which cast will be done in runtime.

```
public static class DynamicEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DynamicCast<T>(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        foreach (dynamic current in source)
        {
            yield return (T)(current);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like

```
 var result = bars.DynamicCast<Foo>();//this works
```

Comment: Thanks. I can write my own extension. I was just hoping that there was a way for `Cast`, the in-build extension to use my operator.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Welcome. But unfortunately AFAIK there is no built in method :(

Comment: Thank you. :-) I am not still saying there should be. I am just saying -- the purpose of my asking this question was -- I've been doing this for years and years and this is one of my pet peeves and I never got a chance to ask if I could twist `Cast` to obey my operator. Appears not. :-)

Comment: This is the correct answer, not the one provided by @EliArabel.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Select`:

```
var manyFoos = manyBars.Select(bar => (Foo)bar);
```

Comment: I know I can do that. Thanks. I am not asking how to project. I am asking -- how do I make Cast use my cast operator? Or how do I make another built in type use my cast without having to manually project/select/transform?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't actually compile. I assume that there is a property "Gar" in the "Bar" class as well?

```
public class Bar
    {
        public string Gar { get; set; }

        public static explicit operator Foo(Bar bar)
        {
            return new Foo(bar.Gar);
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Gar { get; set; }

        public Foo() { }

        public Foo(string gar) { Gar = gar; }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                bars.Add(new Bar() { Gar = i.ToString() });

            var result = bars.Cast<Foo>();
        }
```

+

I encaurage you to read about covariance.

Assuming A is convertible to B, X is covariant if `X<A>` is convertible to `X<B>`.

With C#’s notion of covariance (and contravariance), “convertible” means convertible via an implicit reference conversion— such as A subclassing B, or A implementing B. Numeric conversions, boxing conversions, and custom conversions are not included.

You have to do that with interfaces.