# Getting "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'Win.Models.ResourceModel'."

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am getting this error:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'Win.Models.ResourceModel'."

when executing this code:

```
var qResources = this.dataGridViewResources.Rows
    .Cast<ResourceModel>()
    .AsQueryable();
```

Even though I've built a cast operator in the `ResourceModel`:

```
public static implicit operator ResourceModel(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    List<string> columns = new List<string> { "ResourceName", "Path" };

    List<string> rColumns = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in row.DataGridView.Columns)
    {
        rColumns.Add(c.Name);
    }

    if (!columns.All(c => rColumns.Contains(c))) { return null; }

    return new ResourceModel
    {
        name = row.Cells["ResourceName"].Value.AsString(),
        path = row.Cells["Path"].Value.AsString()
    };
}
```

Now, I've tried it with `explicit` **AND** `implicit`. Both fail with the same error. Is there a way to get the `Cast<ResourceModel>()` to work?

***NOTE:** when placing a breakpoint in the cast operator, it never gets there, so maybe I misunderstand the `Cast<>` method.*

Comment: How about .Select(r => (ResourceModel) r).AsQueryable()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IEnumerable<T>.Cast won't work even if an explicit cast operator is defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953146/ienumerablet-cast-wont-work-even-if-an-explicit-cast-operator-is-defined)

Comment: Check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18953867/2530848) in the same thread

Comment: Yes, of course. Try my `DynamicCast` it should help you (not tested though I tested with explicit cast).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, that worked like a charm my friend!

Comment: @neoistheone Happy to help:) I have no Idea why my answer was not recognized in that thread :(

Comment: You could fix it either by `var qResources = this.dataGridViewResources.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Cast<ResourceModel>()
    .AsQueryable();` but this is poor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User defined implicit/explicit conversion operators are entirely a **compile time** construct.  The runtime has no knowledge of those conversions at all.  Because of that the Linq `Cast` method will never be able to use these user defined conversions.

What's going on is that the *compiler* will notice that you're trying to use a variable of type `DataGridViewRow` where a `ResourceModel` is expected.  Instead of just not compiling, it will search for any user defined conversions to make it work.  If it finds one it inserts the call to that static method around the type to convert it as needed.

So what we need to do is ensure that we're using a `DataGridViewRow` when we need a `ResourceModel` in a way that the *compiler* can see.  We can use `Select` for that:

```
var qResources = this.dataGridViewResources.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>() 
    .Select(row => (ResourceModel)row)
    .AsQueryable();
```

Now the call to the implicit conversion can be added by the compiler, and all is well.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between `implicit` and `explicit`? Both seem to work here.

Comment: @neoistheone Correct, both *will* work here.  Whenever you define an implicit conversion you can use it either implicitly or explicitly.  I'm using it explicitly here, so it doesn't really matter.  There isn't any really good way to use an implicit conversion *in this particular context*.

Comment: So am I correct that `o as FilterModel` would use the `implicit` operator when just executing that statement?

Comment: @neoistheone What is `o` and what is `FileterModel`?  In any case, no, that wouldn't be an implicit conversion, that's an explicit conversion.  An implicit conversion would be something like `ResourceModel m = someDataGridViewRowVariable;`.  That would be explicit if there was a cast there; it's implicit without it.

Comment: Okay, so `implicit` would be `d = i` where `d` is a `double` and `i` is an `int`, right?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your *question* can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808725/why-does-a-linq-castt-operation-fail-when-i-have-an-implicit-cast-defined).

To sole your *problem*, this does not seem like a good "cast" to me, but more of a *conversion*.

I would change your method to a static `ToResourceModel` extension:

```
public static ResourceModel ToResourceModel(this DataGridViewRow row)
{
```

And change your query to:

```
var qResources = this.dataGridViewResources.Rows
    .OfType<DataGridViewRow>() 
    .Select(r => r.ToResourceModel())
    .AsQueryable();
```

If your cast operator is used in other places, or you don't want to change it for some reason, you can use `ConvertAll`:

```
var qResources = this.dataGridViewResources
                     .Rows
                     .OfType<DataGridViewRow>() 
                     .ConvertAll<ResourceModel>(row => (ResourceModel)row)
                     .AsQueryable()
```

Comment: So the problem with that is that `Rows` doesn't yield the `Select` extension, and even if I perform an `AsQueryable`, I still can't yield a `Select`.

Comment: +1 In that I agree this should be an extension method instead of `cast`

Comment: @neoistheone use the `OfType` method to convert the `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`

Comment: @DStanley, okay so got you on the `OfType`. Question though. Why can't I take that `IEnumerable` then and issue the `Cast<ResourceModel>`?

Comment: Because cast operators are static calls that are bound at compile-time.  Enumerable.Cast does a runtime cast, so the static cast operator cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try by selecting first the bound item:

```
var qResources = this.dataGridViewResources.Rows
    .Select(r=>r.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<ResourceModel>()
    .AsQueryable();
```