# C# Conversion Operators not aware of casted to object?

Tags: c#, casting

Could someone explain why a casted to object fails to use an implicit conversion operator? The implicit cast operator seems to be used before it's boxed but once it's boxed it fails.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var wrapper = new GenericWrapper<MemoryStream> { Item = ms };

        object obj = wrapper; 
        object objMs = ms;

        MemoryStream passingImplicitCast = (MemoryStream)wrapper;

        MemoryStream passingCast = (MemoryStream)objMs;
        MemoryStream failingCast = (MemoryStream)obj; //Throws Unable to cast object 
    }
}

class GenericWrapper<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator T(GenericWrapper<T> value)
    {
        return value.Item;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is also not about boxing but about casting.

Comment: I've answered a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18953867/2530848). That should help

Answer (score 0):

Well, test with this line:

```
MemoryStream failingCast = (GenericWrapper<MemoryStream>)obj;
```

In the end, "failingCast" is a `System.IO.MemoryStream`.

[image]

Since `obj` is a `object` you need to be more specific, and set `GenericWrapper<MemoryStream>`. you need to return the value `T`:

Answer (score 0):

You can't surpass type-casting `obj` to `GenericWrapper<MemoryStream>`, because :

1. `object` doesn't know how to convert it self to `MemoryStream`
2. `obj` is originally a `GenericWrapper<MemoryStream>`

your only option is to cast `obj` to `GenericWrapper<MemoryStream>` :

```
MemoryStream failingCast = (MemoryStream)(GenericWrapper<MemoryStream>)obj;
```

and having it type-casted to `GenericWrapper<MemoryStream>`, it now know how to convert it self implicitly to type `MemoryStream` because `GenericWrapper<MemoryStream>` has implicit operator definition.

Comment: You're right, but that's not the only option. You can use dynamic and push the responsiblity oc casting to CLR, that will take care