# Unable to cast object of type MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId to type MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue

Tags: c#, mongodb, casting, bson, objectid

All:

I have IEnumerable called ObjectsList which basically contains a bunch of MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId objects.  I need to cast the entire IEnumerable called ObjectsList into an IEnumerable called BsonValueList

```
           IEnumerable<Object> ObjectsList =     DBConnection.database.GetCollection<ELLCsLog>("FMS_TM_MST_Logs")
                            .FindOneByIdAs<ELLCsInterfaceLog>(ObjectId.Parse(logIdArg.ToString())).logEventsIdList;

           IEnumerable<BsonValue> BsonValueList = ObjectsList.Cast<BsonValue>();
```

Unfortunately, the casting gives the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId to type     MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue  System.SystemException {System.InvalidCastException}
```

Could someone please show the proper code that will cast the aforementioned IEnumerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you want to cast a list of ObjectIds to BsonValues, you need to do a project and explicit cast like this:

```
ObjectsList.Select(v => (BsonValue)v).ToList();
```

I believe it's due to the reasons explained [in the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953146/ienumerablet-cast-wont-work-even-if-an-explicit-cast-operator-is-defined).

In your case where you have a list of Objects rather than ObjectIds, I found you need to put in an additional cast to ObjectId - otherwise you get the same error as with the code you've tried.

```
ObjectsList.Select(v => (BsonValue)(ObjectId)v).ToList();
```

Comment: Thx. I'm new to MongoDB.  Could you tell me the difference between MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId and  MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue  ?  Furthermore, how does MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId and  MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue  relate to the _id in a typical MongoDB collection?

Comment: BSON is MongoDB's serialisation format. ObjectId is a BsonType. Other BsonTypes include Double, String etc. BsonValue is an abstract class which can be a value in a BsonDocument. BsonObjectId is a non-abstract subclass of BsonValue whose Value is of type ObjectId. Others subclasses of BSONValue include BsonDouble, BsonString, but you generally work with the .NET types ObjectId, double, string. The lower level serialisation code works with BsonValues.

Comment: The _id field will be automatically created if you don't specify one, but you can specify one on your POCO with the [BsonId] attribute or naming the field Id. It doesn't have to be an ObjectId.

Answer (score 2):

I have this error once I migrate to .net core. Old Project `using Newtonsoft.Json` and new .net core `using System.Text.Json.Serialization`. You can use one of them or add both `[JosnIgnore]` attributes.

```
[JsonIgnore]
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore] //add this one
[BsonIgnoreIfNull]
[BsonId]
[Ignore]
public BsonValue ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for some cases.